# Can not include style sheet file of wicked_pdf using Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, wicked-pdf

I want to include stylesheet in generated PDF file using wicked_pdf in Rails 3.I have declared some style tag in `test.css` file which is given below.

> stylesheet/test.css:

```
h1{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

I have also included the wicked_pdf stylesheet path in `application.html.erb` file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Generate4</title>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>
  <%= wicked_pdf_stylesheet_link_tag "test" -%>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```

But in the output PDF file no style is displaying.Please check my other files.

> users/test.html.erb:

```
<h1>Hello rails</h1>
```

> users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def download_pdf
         #render pdf: 'test',
           #layout: '/layouts/test',
           #template: '/users/test',
           #handlers: [:erb],
           #formats: [:pdf],
           #:save_to_file => Rails.root.join('public', "test.pdf")
           pdf = render_to_string(pdf: "test.pdf", template: "users/test.html.erb", encoding: "UTF-8")

           send_data pdf ,:disposition => 'inline', filename: 'something.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf'
           save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
            File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
              file << pdf
            end

    end
end
```

> users/index.html.erb:

```
<p>
    <%= link_to "Download Pdf",download_pdf_path(:format => "pdf"),:target => "_blank" %>
</p>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue and display the output with proper declared tag in stylesheet.

Comment: You can specify layout for pdf

Comment: @ user123 : Can you edit the code for getting the proper output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def download_pdf
  pdf = render_to_string(pdf: "test.pdf", template: "users/test.html.erb", encoding: "UTF-8", layout: 'application')
  send_data pdf ,:disposition => 'inline', filename: 'something.pdf', :type => 'application/pdf'
  save_path = Rails.root.join('pdfs','filename.pdf')
  File.open(save_path, 'wb') do |file|
    file << pdf
  end
end
```

application.html.erb

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "test"%>
```

Comment: @ user123 :After adding layout it is throwing error Template is missing

Missing template layouts/application.css with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}. Searched in: * "C:/Site/generate4/app/views"'

Comment: you should replace your css name instead of application.css

Comment: layout value should only be application instead of application.css

Comment: add one line to application.html.erb

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78981/discussion-between-rajat-474-and-user123).